# 'µg' character getting lost with json_encode() -- php

Tags: php, json, string, character-encoding

`var_dump($array)` prints the `µg` (microgram) character fine. when I print the same array using `echo json_ecode($array);` , the `µg` character is replace with `null`.

How to encode the string correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8-encode) to properly encode the string for use in JSON.

Comment: Correction: you have to make sure the string *is* UTF-8 encoded. `utf8_encode` may or may not help there.