# How to deal with 'µg' in PHP?

Tags: php, symbols

So I am having problems with the symbol µg in PHP. The symbol is inside an array of data but I can't seem to match it with the following:

```
if($value == 'µg') {
    echo 'blah';
}
```

Does anyone happen to have a work around for this? I'm assuming PHP saves it as a different type then what I am comparing it to because it never echo's the 'blah' above. I have searched around for a while now and cannot find anything to help me. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a multibyte issue. The `mb_*` functions could be of use here

Comment: maybe useful: [Unicode Character 'MICRO SIGN' (U+00B5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm). Also: ['µg' character getting lost with json_encode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217073/%C2%B5g-character-getting-lost-with-json-encode-php)

Comment: I already tried the utf8_encode and such and had no difference. Thanks though Ryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so even with the help of some people I haven't found the answer.

The best I came up with that actually works is:

```
substr('µg', 1,7) == 'micro;g'
```

That's the only way I found out how to parse the data. If you put the & in front of the micro; you get the µ. A dirty fix but if anyone has a way around please let me know. Thanks!